# CSS3 Transition for nested elements too. Is it posible?

Tags: css

I am trying to build a CSS button, that it is based on this markup:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <i class="icon-facebook"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and what I like to do with that, is to animate the background option for `li` and `a` elements when the mouse is over the `li` or `a` elements

Here is a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/La6my/)** example.

**[jsFiddle UPDATE](http://jsfiddle.net/La6my/2/)**

In the above example you can see that the li is animated, but the inner elements do not get any animation. How can I fix that ?

What I need is to change the `background` option from each nested node when the mouse hovering the `li`element.

Is that posible with CSS3 ?

Kind regards

Comment: If you want sth like parent selector then no. On the other hand do you really need to differ between a:hover and li:hover? Provide some more details please.

Comment: @ogur my question is updated :) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily animate child-elements, but you cannot animate parent elements.

To animate the `a` when you hover the parent `li` element, you can change the selector like following:

```
li:hover a{
    /* now applies to the anchor, when the parent li is hovered*/
}
```

However, you cannot do the same vice versa with the li when the a is hovered.

For that task you need Javascript or the [Selectors Level 4 Subject "Indicator"](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject) which is currently not implemented in any of the browsers.

[Your modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/La6my/1/)

Since those events bubble, it's most likely not necessary to put a hover on the `a` element, but only the `li`.